# Помогите объяснить необычный синтаксис при создании объекта через Object.create()

Tags: javascript, объекты

Столкнулся с необычным для себя синтаксисом создания объекта с помощью `Object.create()`

```js
var Gizza = Object.create({}, {x:{value:10}, y:{get:function(){return this.x*10}}})

document.write(Gizza.y)
```

Код мне понятен. Не понятно, зачем вторым аргументом методу `create()` объекта `Object` передаются свойства которые будут добавляться в `Gizza` именно в том виде, в котором мы видим (я про то, что название свойств это на самом деле ключи к ДЕСКРИПТОРАМ этих свойств). Хм, есть ли в этом какой-то сакральный смысл? Это, чтобы ускорить процесс написания кода, дабы не использовать `Object.defineProperty()` или это из разряда "вот разрабы придумали, так и делай"? Объясните кому не трудно! И если вы голосуете против вопроса, хотя-бы поясняйте почему!

Comment: Что в нём необычного? Он в документации описан https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: @ Alexey Ten , я собственно оттуда этот код почти и выдрал, чуток переделав, НО там нет ответа на мой вопрос, в чём суть этой конструкции? Зачем именно ключи к дескрипторам, а не стандарт в видео prop:val

Comment: Ээээ. Ну потому что это по сути аргумент для defineProperties. И вообще в основном через defineProperty/properties в основном определяются нестандартные свойства. Я вот даже не знаю зачем бы я стал городить огород с этими функциями вместо простого this.prop = val

Comment: @AlexeyTen, например что бы сбросить флаг enumerable, и configurable.

Comment: Ну вот и это уже нестандартное свойство и простой prop:value не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сакрального смысла нет.

Просто данная форма предоставляет более гибкую настройку добавляемых свойств. В частности, как и `defineProperties` позволяет указывать такие параметры свойств, как настраиваемость и перечислимость.

Если взять пример из вопроса, то можно заметить, что данные свойства `x` и `y` оба имеют значение флагов `enumerable` и `configurable` по умолчанию `false`. Что не позволит изменить их в создаваемом объекте, а также позволит избежать их при обходе с помощью [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) либо [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var Gizza = Object.create({}, {x:{value:10}, y:{get:function(){return this.x*10}}})

console.log(Gizza.x, Gizza.y);

Gizza.x = 1;
console.log(Gizza.x, Gizza.y);
console.log(Object.keys(Gizza));

Gizza.z = 1;
for(var i in Gizza){
  console.log(i, Gizza[i]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, единственное, хотелось бы услышать ещё , используется ли такая форма записи программистами? Или это экзотика?

Comment: @Muranx, вполне может использоваться